# Codeigniter email issue with gmail

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

This is my code:

```
$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('myemail@gmail.com');
$this->email->cc('myemail2@gmail.com');

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

$this->email->send();
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

This is the result of echo:

```
Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: mail

From: "Your Name" <your@example.com>
Return-Path: <your@example.com>
Cc: myemail2@gmail.com
Reply-To: "your@example.com" <your@example.com>
X-Sender: your@example.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <55058c9e98942@example.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
=?utf-8?Q?Email_Test?=
Testing the email class.
```

I am testing a contact form. At first try I received the message, even if I got this message in gmail account `"This message may not have been sent by: myemail@gmail.com"`

I tried with the mail function from php:

```
$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: myemail2@gmail.com";
```

But I did not receive any email. What should I do ? What am I doing wrong ?

UPDATE:

```
        $config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
        $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $config['priority'] = 1;

        $this->email->initialize($config);
        $this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
        $this->email->to('cazare.carei.strand@gmail.com');
        $this->email->cc('naghi.attila@gmail.com');

        $this->email->subject('Email Test');
        $this->email->message('Testing the email class.'); 

        $this->email->send();
        echo $this->email->print_debugger(); exit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your port 25 is open, the e-mail should be sendable. Some e-mail providers require a valid [mx record](http://support.name.com/entries/21077306-What-is-an-MX-record-) to be set in the DNS-Records of the e-mail's domain from the sender to prohid fake-emails of unauthorized senders being sent.

I am not sure if gmail has this requirement.

If you like to catch that issue you reconfigure the DNS entries of example.com to contain your server's ip address. An other possibility is to sendout the e-mail using a forign smtp server instead of your server's internal sendmail. I made the experience that this can be slow (on a big webabbplication).

As [found on google](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html), you can use with codignither for the protocol entry in the *mail configuration* also: 'sendmail'.

**EDIT:**

> "This message **may not have been sent by**: myemail@gmail.com"

This might indicate that Google does not trust the sending server.

Comment: I am not sending it from a local machine. I change the email into a yahoo account, but neither there i not receive any message

Comment: Your non local machine must have it's ip in the dns-entries of example.com. You can try e-mailing me. jakob -dot- eichler [at] altergear -dot- net because my server does not check again valid mx records.

Let me know in here after you sent the mail, so I can remove my e-mail address.

Even if the A record of the domain points to the mail-server your mx record should be propperly set.

Comment: Please check my update in my post. I still not receive any emails :(

Comment: It is really weird, first it works, but when i change the subject ,from and message with my data, it didn;t work after that i put it back, but it does not work

Comment: Did you try to send me an e-mail. According to my theory the "from" is what matters.

Comment: Yep I sent it now. Weird: now its working the same code. I don;t understand

Comment: If i put my email address to from it works. If i put some random emails, it does not work . WHY  ?

Comment: I got your (e-mail) message. I already told you the answer to that question. Please read and verify my answer and vote it up.

My server should accept your mails even with a random -from- part.

Comment: example.com has an mx record set.

okam@localhost:~$ dig mx IN exmaple.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.2-Ubuntu <<>> mx IN exmaple.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 44545
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;exmaple.com.   IN MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
exmaple.com.  86400 IN MX 10 numpty.absolutelyplastered.com.